# How can I achieve this layout in WPF C#?

Tags: c#, wpf, layout

As you can see in this image:

[image]

It's a table containing different controls(e.g. button, list, text) on the columns that can be sorted and each row is unique to each other. Any help or starting point would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please read [this post](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You would typically have an [Observable Collection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604(v=vs.110).aspx) which holds the objects of interest (i.e. in your screenshot you have a person with a name, age, etc), so it could potentially be an ObservableCollection of Person objects.

Once you have that, you can build up your view in XAML. Typically you'd have some sort of list control ([list view](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh943062.aspx), list box, etc) that binds to the collection, and you create a [data template](http://wpftutorial.net/DataTemplates.html) in order to customise the look and feel of the control to match how it looks in the screenshot.